# VS2012 Azure webrole properties read-only

Tags: visual-studio-2012, azure

I try to create separate configurations for different installations of my Azure webrole. I have two separate installations with different domain names. These are pretty much the same roles with different connection strings settings. Now I'm adding https and encounter a problem.

I have managed to create multiple ServiceConfiguration files and publish profiles. Now I'm trying to edit configurations. When I right-click on Role on Solution Explorer and select Properties, GUI appears. 
Now for the interesting part. When "All Configurations" is selected, settings can be altered. When I select a configuration, all settings are getting disabled. This looks wrong.

The question is: why the settings are greyed and how can it be mended?